# Why can't I pass my register request as a login request while they both inherit from request?

Tags: laravel, request

I made a RegistrationRequest and a LoginRequest and when I register the user I login the user immediatly. But when I try to pass the RegistrationRequest into my LoginRequest I get the following error

[image]

Can you not pass requests on to other functions? I did it with normal requests and that worked fine, but I gues the are of the same type.

```
public function login(LoginRequest $request)
{
    $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

    if ($token = $this->guard()->attempt($credentials))
        return $this->respondWithToken($token);

    return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthorized'], 401);
}

public function register(RegistrationRequest $request)
{
    $user = User::create([
        'user_name' => $request->user_name,
        'first_name' => $request->first_name,
        'last_name' => $request->last_name,
        'email' => $request,
    ]);

    return response()->json([
        'success'   =>  true,
        'data'      =>  $user,
        'meta'      =>  $this->login($request),
    ], 200);
}
```

Comment: strict type won't accept other types see your methods .. you could use Request type and it would work fine otherwise check https://stackoverflow.com/a/59806468/176578 answer

Comment: Yeah, His $request from `RegistrationRequest` instance, Hence the error is occurring